# Is it a problem for otherwise healthy humans to take choline and vitamin B12 together?

Tags: b-12-supplements, neurotransmitter

It was written in [the conclusion chapter here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11833752/#:%7E:text=Folate%20adequacy%20may%20increase%20B12,metabolic%20pathway%20cannot%20be%20used.):

> Folate adequacy may increase B12 use for homocysteine metabolism, thus limiting B12 availability for methylmaIonic acid metabolism. Choline use may also increase, and choline deficiency may worsen if choline substitutes when the vitamin B12 side of the homocysteine metabolic pathway cannot be used.

Perhaps due to not being a native speaker of English and/or not knowing enough about biochemistry, I misunderstand this passage.

Is it a problem for otherwise healthy humans to take choline and vitamin B12 together?

Comment: That passage isn't about healthy people; it's about people with a choline deficiency. I don't think it says anything about choline and B12 in a healthy subject.

Comment: Also, be aware that questions about diet and nutrition are off topic here unless directly related to medical treatment. Since you brought a medical treatment issue into the question with your source, I'll leave it open, but be aware in the future.